# Unexpected behaviour of current sensing circuit with op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-sensing

I would like to use the schematic below to measure the output current of a buck converter (0-10 A) and convert it to a voltage of 0-3.3 V which is read by a microcontroller. During startup I sometimes run into the problem which I have simulated below.

When the voltage at the sense resistor drops to near 0 V, the op-amp (LM324) output jumps to the supply voltage of 24 V and stays there. Since the input voltage is close to 0 V I would expect some undesired behaviour like this, but I don't understand why it does not 'recover'? What would be the best way to resolve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Two things to consider: what is the Voh and Vol of the [LM324](https://datasheet.octopart.com/LM324M-ON-Semiconductor-datasheet-506186.pdf) (how close can the outputs get to the power rails?)  And what is the intrinsic junction capacitance of the BZX8VB8V2LY [BZX84-B8V2](https://datasheet.octopart.com/BZX84-B8V2%2C215-Philips-datasheet-8361847.pdf)?  Likely 450pF.  When charged, how is this junction capacitance discharged?

Comment: Do you have it wired for positive feedback instead of negative? It's difficult to tell the input pins apart.

Comment: That circuit cannot do what you want. You are trying to read 10A through a 10 mOhm resistor, which is 100 mV, with a common mode voltage that varies from zero to probably 10 volts or more, and you need a gain of 30. If you can put the sense resistor on the low side, a simple non-inverting amplifier will work. Otherwise you really need a high side current monitor, best accomplished with an appropriate IC.

Comment: Is it possible that you're forward-biasing the base-collector junction in Q1, resulting in accidental positive feedback?

Comment: What is the output voltage range of the buck converter? That's quite important, as different circuit topologies will be necessary depending on what's the bottom and top end of the range.

Comment: @rdtsc When the problem occurs the output voltage of the op-amp is decreasing until approximately 0.6 V and then jumps to Vcc. If I read the datasheet I am still above Vol which would be a few 10 mV? (Exact value is not in the datasheet for Vcc = 24 V).

Comment: @Null Apologies, it is indeed not very clear in the schematic. The collector of Q1 is connected to the non-inverting input of the op-amp.

Comment: @PStechPaul The past few days this circuit seemed to be working, it is only when I lowered the buck converter output voltage from 12V to 3-4 V that I started running into this problem during the startup of the buck converter. Also, I am trying to do it without a current sensing IC because they are typically low in stock.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica The output voltage range of the buck converter for my application will probably be from 3-4 V to 15V.

Comment: @brhans Yes I think the base-collector junction becomes forward biased when the opamp output voltage jumps to near Vcc. However I do not fully understand why and what effect this has, could you elaborate a bit please? Is it because the opamp output drops below 0.6-0.7V so Vbe of Q1 also drops below the threshold and causes Q1 to no longer conduct?

Comment: I think it happens before that. The B-C junction getting forward-biased causes the positive feedback which makes the output jump up to Vcc. Most of the time, your opamp's negative feedback comes from Q1 conducting and drawing current away from the opamp's non-inverting input through R1 in order to get the non-inverting input to almost the same voltage level as the inverting input. But that feedback mechanism will only really work as long as the opamp's output stays below the voltage at the non-inverting input - and the lower your input voltage the closer you get to where things go wrong ...

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your schematic, I can't see what Q1 is supposed to do, but it seems as if the inverting nature of Q1 should make the loop feedback negative.

However, one thing that stands out is that it is easily possible for Q1's base potential (the op-amp output) to exceed its collector potential, and forward bias the base-collector junction. If that happens, then collector potential will "follow" the base, and feedback becomes positive.

I think that's why your op-amp locks up in a high state.

Since I don't know what Q1 is supposed to achieve here, the best answer I can give you is a suggestion which wouldn't suffer from this problem, but doesn't use Q1:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAyY7b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That's just a basic differential amplifier, with gain of 33. It behaves like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you must use a high-side current monitor, you could try a circuit like the one I have simulated below. It won't be accurate for input voltages near zero, but it is within 1% from 5 V to 35 V, for which I use a 15 V sine wave with 20 V DC offset.

The output voltage between R2 and R4 (a and b) equals the voltage on the 100 mΩ shunt R5 (Vin and Vout). It also works with a 10 mΩ shunt, but the error increases to about 5%-8% for common-mode voltages of less than 6 V. If you do this, you may need to tweak the values to get the performance you desire, and you will still need an amplifier with a gain of 30 to get the required signal to your ADC.

[image: High Side Current Monitor]

I was able to achieve about 1% error down to a range of 1 V to 39 V with a 10 mΩ shunt by using 975 Ω for R1 and R3, and 1 MΩ for R7.

I simulated the OP's circuit using an AD820 and 2N2222, and the output was basically slammed to the 24 V Vcc rail.

OK. Here is a practical circuit, although it also has some unwanted behavior, which might be due to the simulator. For one thing, the voltage across the shunt resistor should not be distorted (or go below zero).

[image: High Side Current Monitor with two AD820 Op-amps]

I was not really satisfied with the last circuit, so I came up with the following, using a current mirror and a single op-amp. I also used a step function to test it for a range of power supply voltages. This still needs very close matching of the differential amplifier resistors:

[image: High Side Current Mirror PNP]

I simulated the circuit provided by @emdura, and found problems with it. However, I used most of the same components and made some changes that work properly. The source follower MOSFET is not really necessary, but is provided in case higher output current is desired. At least this design does not depend on the value of the load resistor.

[image: High Side Current Monitor @emdura]

Comment: thank you for your elaborate anwser, for now I have resolved my problem in a different way, but I might still try out your circuit as well

Comment: I discovered that my circuit is extremely sensitive to the exact values and ratios of the resistors. And the transistors must be very well matched. So probably not all that practical.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your comments/anwsers! I seem to have resolved my problem by replacing Q1 with a mosfet and I also added some capacitive feedback (see below). I updated my prototyping board with these changes as well and the microcontroller indeed seems to return the actual output current of my buck converter.

[image]

Comment: Yep - by using a MOSFET there you'll never run into the problem in your original circuit where the forward-biased BC junction gives you runaway positive feedback.

Comment: I don't think that will work. You have the variable voltage source connected to the drain of the MOSFET, through a 1k resistor R4, and the low side of the shunt connects to the Op-amp inverting input through R3. The output of the op-amp drives the gate of the MOSFET, but it will always be fully ON, and you will be reading the voltage on Rload. However, that would be a 5.5V sine wave on 9.5V offset which is V(n004). So I don't see how you got that.

Comment: OK, I simulated it, and got the same results you did. However, the gain (30) seems to be related to the ratio of R4 and R6. And it becomes unstable and oscillates if I change R4 from 1k to 2k. It also oscillates with offset 5V and 3V sine wave (or even 0.5V). It seems an offset of 6 or 7 volts or less causes instability.

Answer (score 0):

Real op-amps have offset. You'll have to add the worst-case offset to the input plus a small margin. Then it won't saturate. But that will require a slightly different design.

You have two choices:

1. Use a purpose-made high sensing current shunt amplifier. Those usually are easy to interface straight to 3.3V ADC inputs.

   The upside: one chip. The downside: there are no industry standard pinouts/specs, so if the part is not available, you either have to wait or redesign.
2. Use a discrete design.

   The upside: if you can't buy the parts, the world is ending and you don't need to worry about it anymore :) The downside: more drift, but performance can be improved by using better op-amps in the same package.

There isn't much to applying high-side sensors if you follow their datasheet and/or app notes. So we'll explore a discrete design.

OA1 copies scaled version of the input current onto R6. I2 driving R2 adds an offset voltage that compensates for worst-case offsets in OA1 and elsewhere in the system. I2 would be e.g. an LM334, or any other current source with compliance voltage range from 10 to 25V.

OA2 mirrors the current from R6 onto R9 and R11.

OA3 buffers the output voltage.

D1-R10 establish about 4V of headroom from the top rail, so that the op-amp inputs are within their common-mode range.

V1, V2 and V3 are used to model op-amp offset voltages.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5skrC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output voltage waveform is shown below. The load is driven with a 1kHz 0-10A sine wave current waveform. The top and bottom curves are for the worst case input offset voltage in OA1, since that offset dwarfs the others.

[image]

This circuit always recovers from disturbances even if they saturate the outputs.

To improve performance, use op-amps with more gain, better linearity and offset drift. The requirements for the op-amps are modest:

- OA1, OA2

  1. Input common mode range from (V-) to (V+)-2V.
  2. Output voltage range: (V-)+2V to (V+)-2V.
- OA3 - if powered from 24V (eg LM324):

  1. Input common mode range from (V-) to (V+)-2V.
  2. Output voltage range: (V-) to (V+)-5V.
- OA3 - if powered from 5V:

  1. Input common mode range: (V-) to (V+)-2V.
  2. Output voltage range: (V-) to (V+)-2V.
- OA3 - if powered from 3.3V:

  1. Input common mode range: rail-to-rail
  2. Output voltage range: rail-to-rail

R12 ensures LM324 performance with output close to 0V. It should be removed for other op-amp families, unless the datasheet dictates otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate anwser, for now I have resolved my problem in a different way, but I might still try out your circuit as well